# Design table for many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I am building a reservations app and I would like an advice on how to design the models.
I have **Reservation** and **Table** model currently designed like this:

```
class Table < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :reservations
end
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

However, often the restaurant needs to make 1 reservation for several tables - for a group of 10 people 2 tables are joined together and both of them should not be available at the given time. In this case, I have 2 options:

- Create 2 identical reservations for the 2 tables(easy but seems unnecessary as there might be events with 10 tables needed)
- Create a new model **ReservationTable** and changing the models to:

> ```
> class Table < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :restaurant
>   has_many :reservation_tables
>   has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_tables
> end
>
> class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :restaurant
>   has_many :reservation_tables
>   has_many :tables, through: :reservation_tables
> end
>
> class ReservationTable < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :reservation
>   belongs_to :table
> end
> ```

Which choice do you think is better in the long-run(and if the second, is the design accurate?)?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The ReservationTable method looks good.

Logically, it is redundant to directly associate the Reservation with the Restaurant if they are also associated via ReservationTable and Table, but I can see that there might be states during the life of the reservation when there might not be tables assigned so based on that I wouldn't change it.